# Connecting with ssh through the shell?

Tags: ssh, go, command-line-interface

I am working with Go trying to automate keeping track of all of my ssh connections. I am having some issues running the command from Go. Here is my code:

```
cmd := exec.Command("ssh", string(c.Address))
        cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
        cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        err2 := cmd.Run()
        if err2 != nil {
            fmt.Print("Disconnected")
        }
```

c.Address is equivalent to "person@192.168.1.1" not using that ip obviously but when I run this I get the following error.

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.1.1
: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I can connect just fine using ssh from my terminal.

Thanks!

Comment: Try printing some debug output from the `ssh` command, and comparing it the same command from the shell.

Comment: Also, make sure c.Address doesn't contain any extra whitespace or unprintable characters.

Comment: Weird one. Try localhost. Isn't c.Address a function? (being tired happens ;). Not related to address resolution, but who knows: Try with an absolute path to the ssh executable, in the unlikely event that your PATH has something to do with it. What OS are you using? That might be helpful to know.

Comment: c.Address is the string field of a struct. I am running this on a Mac. I tried to split the user name and the ip up and got the following.

    ssh: connect to host  port 22: Connection refused

Comment: If you can connect to the same IP from the command line, then there's definitely something wrong with your ssh arguments. Have you tried to use a constant string, like `cmd := exec.Command("ssh", "192.168.1.1") ...` This would eliminate any suspicions regarding `c.Address`. To check if `c.Adress` is really what you expect it to be, you can dump it with `fmt.Printf("%+q\n", c.Address)` (guarantees ascii output).

Comment: Oh, just noticed that you're converting `c.Address` to a string, is it a fixed size `[]byte` slice by any chance? Any garbage at the end of the slice like trailing 0's would be added to the string. See [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/oYqsjtci24).

Comment: you could give the package golang.org/x/crypto/ssh a try 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` package.

[Package documentation.](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh)

[Nice tutorial to get you started.](http://golang-basic.blogspot.com/2014/06/step-by-step-guide-to-ssh-using-go.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have

`cmd := exec.Command("ssh", string("root@192.168.1.1"))`

it works. As per the comment above if you have

`cmd := exec.Command("ssh", string("root@192.168.1.1 "))` - notice the extra space

then you will get the error you you described.